# Why are my included progress bars getting the same progress value?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a viewPager with 2 fragments.
The problem is inside the first fragment. It contains the following **layout.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include  
       android:id="@+id/first"
       layout="@layout/view_part"/>
   <include  
       android:id="@+id/second"
       layout="@layout/view_part"/>
   <include  
       android:id="@+id/third"
       layout="@layout/view_part"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now for **view_part.xml** (the included layout)

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <!-- some other views -->

   <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For the **onCreateView** method inside the fragment I have:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
       (RelativeLayout) rl1 = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.first);
       (RelativeLayout) rl2 = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.second);
       (RelativeLayout) rl3 = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.third);

       ((ProgressBar) rl1.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar)).setProgress(25);
       ((ProgressBar) rl2.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar)).setProgress(50);
       ((ProgressBar) rl3.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar)).setProgress(75);

       return rootView;
 }
```

The first time the fragment loads everything is fine. All progress bars have different progress shown.

However when I rotate the screen, or the fragment gets automatically deallocated by the viewPager it calls onCreateView function again but this time all progressBars show 75% which is the last one that I set.

Comment: Did you try placing the progress in `onResume`?

Comment: But the fragment is being re-created. It gets destroyed and I used android studio debugger to see that it goes through onCreateView all over again.

Comment: By the way, texviews are working correctly. My issue is only with progressBars

Comment: Don't you see that you are setting a progress to the same progress-bar three times in a row? A call to 'findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar)' three times with the same view ID.

Comment: OK. My bad. I haven't noticed that you're using <include>